# MAUI Blazor How to disable webview iOS elastic bounce?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

In iOS even with the default app, there is a scroll on the whole layout that i would like to remove, it doesn't seems to be caused by the css, at least in android it doesn't appear.
What I've tried to do is use a custom renderer but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
public class WkWebViewCustomRenderer : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewRenderer<BlazorWebView, WKWebView>
{
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BlazorWebView> e)
     {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);

         if (Control == null)
         {
             var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
             var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
             webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
             webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
             SetNativeControl(webView);
         }
         if (e.NewElement != null)
         {
             Control?.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://0.0.0.0")));
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to customize the WebView.

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewRenderer<BlazorWebView, WKWebView>
    {

        public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
         {
         }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
         {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            ScrollView.Bounces = false;
         }

       protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

For more information, you can refer to [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview).

Comment: This doesn't seem to compile, OnElementChanged cant be override, HybridWebView isn't available in any namespace and the constructor doesn't take 1 argument even with using the base one like in the example on the link you posted